Unity rigidbody and colliders send everything spinning
So I have my player with a rigidbody (use gravity false and is kinematic false), and a capsule collider (isTrigger false) but when they move around the room, I want the walls to stop them, the walls I have a box collider (isTrigger false). The game runs ok if the player doesn't touch the walls, but once the players touches the wall, every game object just starts to spin in space and look like it's falling.
I've tried reading up on rigid bodies and colliders but it's very confusing for me, as well as all the options (trigger, gravity, etc). Does anyone know what's wrong with my combination?
At this point I think I've blindly tried every combination but none of them have the desired effect.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
